# How to do the deltas on each column in a table?

Tags: dolphindb

I create a table using the following scripts:

```py
sym = take(1, 110)
id = 1..100 join take(int(),10)
id2 =  take(int(1),10) join 1..100
t = table(sym, id,id2)
```

How to get the deltas results of each column?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following code:

```py
sym = take(1, 110)
id = 1..100 join take(int(),10)
id2 =  take(int(1),10) join 1..100
t = table(sym, id,id2)
each(x->x.deltas(), t.values())
```